# Passing props to child components with a React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-props

I'm trying to figure out how to pass props to the 'Camera' component but getting a syntax error when i try

```
component= { Camera doSomething={this.doSomething}}
```

cant seem to find documentation to help on this one.  Im sure its simple if you know how - hoping someone can assist.

my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Camera from './camera'
import VideoComponent from './video'
import AudioComponent from './audio'
import File from './file'
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from 'react-native-vector-icons';


const CaptureNav = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();


class Capture extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <CaptureNav.Navigator >

        <CaptureNav.Screen 
          name="Camera" 
          component= {Camera}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon : () => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons name='camera' color={'black'} size={26} />
            )
          }}
        />

        <CaptureNav.Screen 
          name="Video" 
          component= {VideoComponent} 

        />

        <CaptureNav.Screen 
          name="Audio" 
          component= {AudioComponent}

        />

         <CaptureNav.Screen 
          name="File" 
          component= {File} 

        />

      </CaptureNav.Navigator>
    )
  }
}

export default Capture
```

Comment: You need to pass your component to the  react navigation component props like component={<Camera {...props} />}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Stack.Screen name="Home">
  {props => <HomeScreen {...props} extraData={someData} />}
</Stack.Screen>
```

[check this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation/)