# How to pass params to Stack from an other Stack React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

My problem is that I have a Profile Stack that contains all the screens that you can reach from your / user's profile. I put this Stack to my DrawerStack and also to my HomeScreen Stack because these are the two possible ways to navigate there. But when I navigate there with some params it says that the route's params are undefined.

**Profile Stack**

```
function ProfileNavigator() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="ProfileScreen" component={Profile} />
      ...Other Screens
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

**Home Navigator**

```
function HomeNavigator() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" options={{headerShown: false}} component={Home} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Profile" options={{headerShown: false}} component={ProfileNavigator}/>
      ... Other Screens
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

**Drawer Navigator**

```
<NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator
        drawerContent={props => <CustomDrawerNavigator {...props} />}
        initialRouteName="Home">
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={BottomNavigator} />
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="Profile"
          options={{headerShown: false}}
          component={ProfileNavigator}
        />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

**Navigate to the Profile**

```
onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Profile', {current_user: true})}
```

I can pass Params and Navigate to the Profile If I don't use Stack but then I have to add every Profile Screens to every other Stack and I don't think is it efficient. I read somewhere that the similar names can cause such a problem but I just couldn't wrap my head around the problem.

Comment: Check this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60664242/passing-props-to-child-components-with-a-react-navigation/60665670#60665670

Answer (score 0):

So finally I found the answer in the docs.

I had to navigate like this:

props.navigation.navigate('Profile', {
      screen: 'Profile',
      params: { current_user: true },
    });

And I also changed the ProfileScreen name to Profile in the ProfileNavigator.